# Compare Row of 1st Datatable with Column of 2nd Datatable and build 3rd datatable with matched columns

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datatable, comparison

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/733071/Compare-Row-of-1st-Datatable-with-Column-of-2nd-Da
(Understand the question)
THESE ARE MY TWO DATATABLES (visual c#)

```
table1

|Par Name.........| Par #|.......Units |.......LSL  |   USL | -----SKIP |
Diffusion.........908513100.......-..........  0  -----99.9  -----1 
Program...........908514100.......-.........  99.5--- 999    -----





table2
starttime   | Product      | Device   | Diffusion       | Program | 
11/7/2013    SAF5100EL       163       -0.145712003      -0.146583006                                 
11/7/2013    SAF5100EL        84       -0.137499005      -0.137592003
11/7/2013    SAF5100EL        44       -0.142690003      -0.143250003  
11/7/2013    SAF5100EL       164       -0.139434993      -0.140459001
11/7/2013    SAF5100EL        34       -0.147183999      -0.148519993
```

output should look like

```
table3 
  |Diffusion|       | Program |
 -0.145712003      -0.146583006
 -0.137499005      -0.137592003
 -0.142690003      -0.143250003
 -0.139434993      -0.140459001
 -0.147183999      -0.148519993
```

here the columns in table2 which match the row names of table1(for instance here diffusion and program) have to be fetched from datatable2 and new DataTable3 has to be created and with sorted values of columns (Diffusion and Program)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service but the people here are happy to help you improve what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, this is straight forward logic and that you should try it yourself first. This will give you confidence as well.

Anyways, the following code should do the trick. Tweek it as per your convenience. Also test it thoroughly.

```
//dt1 contains Diffusion etc as rows
//dt2 contains diffusion etc as columns
//dt3 is the required table
DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
DataRow dr = null;

for (int i = 0; i < dt1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string col = dt1.Rows[i]["Par Name"].ToString();
    if (dt2.Columns.Contains(col))
    {
        if (!dt3.Columns.Contains(col))
        {
            dt3.Columns.Add(col, typeof(string));
        }

        if (dt3.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < dt2.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                dr = dt3.NewRow();
                dt3.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < dt2.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            dt3.Rows[j][col] = dt2.Rows[j][col].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for all your effort @samar.             I want to know awhat this  dt1.Rows[i]["Par Name"].ToString()        what does this statement does ?

Comment: That gets the value at ith Row and of "Par Name" column and converts the value to string. If you do not write .ToString() the value will be of type object

Comment: It is working Now.Got the table finally. I want to sort the Values in Ascending order for each column that is in table 3.How do I do that

Comment: You should try it out yourself. This will give you confidence. Search on the net, there are tons of examples for the same. If not possible then please raise a new question for the same.

Comment: Samar this works like a charm :)...I am working on this thanks to you